# how to get the namespaces in the root of xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml whose root has namespaces like

```
 <root version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sample.org/schemas/2009 http://www.sample1.org/schemas/2009/railML-2.0/railML.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dc="http://xyz/elements/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.abcd.org/schemas/2009">
```

I am able to retrieve the value of xmlns using

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlToParse);
 Console.WriteLine(xdoc.Root.Name.NamespaceName);
```

but how can i get the values of other namespaces in root i.e. value of

```
xsi
dc
schemaLocation
```

Before parsing I need to verify these namespaces so i need these values.
how to do it?
can it be done by linq how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var q = xdoc.Root.Attributes()
                 .Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                 .Select(x => new {Prefixes = x.Name.LocalName, ns = x.Value});
```

**EDIT:**

More Ways: [Get namespaces from an XML Document with XPathDocument and LINQ to XML](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx)